when using eclipse wikitext markdown, the preview is blank
When I invoke the wikitext markdown editor and switch to the preview tab the contents are blank. Eclipse version installed is 4.30.0. The wikitext plugin are installed.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.10 (Ootpa)

Anything showing in the Error Log view? What's it supposed to be previewing (a screenshot would probably help a lot)?

This seems to be the first if several when the markdown file is opened: !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2024-08-30 09:49:15.176
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.findNext: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.FindNextAction@5d887ffc)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.FindNextAction@5d887ffc)} in: PartImpl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor)  removeOnHide org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui.editor.markupEditorContext
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting handlers: {[ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.FindNextAction@5d887ffc),  for 'org.eclip

It does not matter the markdown file, they all show blank preview.

I did have another markdown editor installed. I uninstalled it and restarted eclipse. No improvement.
